# Ionic 2 App Back button behaviour to navigate to another page

Tags: ionic2, angular2-routing

I have used this.navCtrl.push() to navigate to a new page on click of a button. It creates a default back button clicking which takes me back to the previous page. I want to navigate to another page on click of the back button. How can I do that ?

I have tried this but it doesn't work :

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public platform: Platform) {
  platform.ready().then(()=>{
       platform.registerBackButtonAction(()=>this.myHandlerFunction());
});
  }
myHandlerFunction(){
this.navCtrl.setRoot(VesselsearchPage);

}
```

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45361250/5393271)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inject Platform from 'ionic-angular' and then register a new handler to the back button action:

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(private platform: Platform) { }

ionViewWillEnter(): void {
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => this.backButtonFunc());
}

private backButtonFunc(): void {
     // do something 
}
```