# NavController doesn't work in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application, ionic4

I'm injecting NavController in my constructor as I want to push a page. But, below code doesn't work in Ionic 4. It was totally okay in Ionic 3.

> Constructor

```
constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController, public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
   }
```

> Method

```
goToSecondPage()
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(list);
  }
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Did you import `NavController`?

Comment: Ofcourse! `import { MenuController, NavController } from '../../../../node_modules/@ionic/angular';`

Comment: You should just be able to use `import { MenuController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';`. What error/s are you getting?

Comment: `import { MenuController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';` isn't work for me. Because, it can't find **ionic-angular**. I also searched Ionic 4 documentation. But, this is not clear. @JosephWebber

Comment: Checking out the [Ionic 4 API](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/), I couldn't find any info on `NavController`, only `Nav`. Try changing `NavController` to `Nav` and see if that works.

Comment: `this.navCtrl.goForward('/list');` it's work for Ionic 4! Ionic 4 suggests to use angular routing. But, now the problem is there is no back button in navbar when I go to the second page!

Comment: `import { MenuController, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';`. About back button you need to add it yourself now : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/BREAKING.md#back-button

Comment: use below method: this.navController.navigateRoot('/cmspagedetail/'+id);

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Now, to complete the final step and implement those routes in our **app-routing.module.ts** file, they would look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'home', loadChildren: './pages/home/home.module#HomeModule' },
{ path: 'products', loadChildren: './pages/products/products.module#ProductsModule'},
{ path: 'products/:id', loadChildren: './pages/product-detail/product-detail.module#ProductDetailModule' },
{ path: 'products/categories', loadChildren: './pages/product-categories/product-categories.
{ path: 'support', loadChildren: './pages/support/support.module#SupportModule' }
];
```

setRoot in html page

```
<ion-button href="/support" routerDirection="root">
```

or in class

```
this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/support');
```

**Push**

```
<ion-button href="/products/12" routerDirection="forward">
```

or

```
this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/products/12');
```

**Pop**

```
<ion-button href="/products" routerDirection="backward">
```

or

```
<ion-back-button defaultHref="/products"></ion-back-button>
```

you can also navigate backwards programatically:

```
this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/products');
```

p/s: https://www.joshmorony.com/converting-ionic-3-push-pop-navigation-to-angular-routing-in-ionic-4/

Answer (score 9):

NavController as this is deprecated in IONIC 4.

Structure is like this.

```
     V3                 V4
/src/pages     ->   /src/app/pages
/src/models    ->   /src/app/models
/src/providers ->   /src/app/providers
```

- You can use pages if you have pages directory.
- You can use parameters if you want to pass it.

  this.router.navigate('/pages, { locs: this.locId }])');

Example: With Pages directory.

```
this.router.navigate(['/list'], { locs: this.locId }]);
```

Example: Without Pages directory and parameters.

```
this.router.navigate(['/list']);
```

This link is useful for the tabs.
For more Info go through this link.
[https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/upgrading-an-ionic-3-application-to-ionic-4-eaf81a53cdea][1]

---

Extras:

> After navigate to new page, we can get the locsId using `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('locs')` by importing `private
>   route: ActivatedRoute` inside the current page constructor

Example:

```
export class ListPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log("this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get : ", this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('locs'));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: fyi, more on how to use Router in ionic v4 https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-the-change-with-ionic-4-and-angular-router/

Answer (score 5):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
 ...
})
export class LoginComponent {
 constructor(private router: Router){}

    navigate(){
       this.router.navigate(['/detail'])
    }
}
```

[for more info click here](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/navigation/angular#navigating-to-different-routes)

Comment: Hi Edward, thanks for submitting an answer. While your answer is helpful, it might be more helpful if you included some information other than code that answers the original question. It's best to avoid just linking to documentation.

Answer (score 4):

> Try (in **ionic 4**)

```
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
```

> instead of (in **ionic 3**)

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular'
```

Answer (score 2):

first import navcontroller
 **import { NavController, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';**
and now go forward also dont support it was best in ionic 3
**this.nav.navigateForward('/ChatPage')** supported in ionic 4 for but my sugesstion one should use angular routing

Answer (score 1):

```
this.navCtrl.push(list);
```

It doesn't work in Ionic 4. Ionic 4 is based on Angular Routing. So, just use the following code, and write a route for this.

```
this.navCtrl.goForward('/list');
```

> For back button in NavBar

Paste following code in `<ion-toolbar> </ion-toolbar>` for back button in the 2nd page.

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button  defaultHref="home"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
```

Answer (score 1):

IONIC 4 - Angular (ionic start appName --type=angular)

**Physical Back Button** and **Back Button Menu**

In the Target page (second page), do:

**SecondPage TS**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-second',
      templateUrl: './second.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./second.page.scss'],
    })
    export class SecondPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

        inscBackAction: Subscription;
        element: HTMLElement;

        constructor(
          private router: Router, 
          public platform: Platform) {
        }

        ngOnInit() {    
          this.inscBackAction = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
            // Check this log in chrome: "chrome://inspect/#devices"
            console.log('Physical Back Button');                

            this.element = document.getElementById('backButton') as HTMLElement;
            this.element.click();
            // OR
            // this.router.navigate(['/anyPage']);

          }, error => {
            console.log('\n\nERROR:\n' + error.message + '\n\n');
          });
        }

        ngOnDestroy() {
          this.inscBackButton.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
```

**SecondPage HTML**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
      <!-- Does not work with #backButton -->
      <ion-back-button id="backButton" defaultHref="/"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Second
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding></ion-content>
```

_

P.S.:

May be necessary for menu links in HTML:

```
[routerDirection] = "'forward'"
```

Like in "app.component.html" on projects *sidemenu*

```
<ion-item [routerDirection]="'forward'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
```

See More:https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/buttons/

Answer (score 1):

You could just fix this by using "import { navController } from 'ionic-angular'"
But that's gonna give you an error with Rxjs. So you might wanna do this...

In your app-routing.module.ts, make sure your pages and their modules are correctly specified in the path and loadChildren. Here's mine

```
const routes: Routes = [ { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },

{ path: 'register', loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterPageModule' },
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
{ path: 'register', loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterPageModule' },
];
```

In my login.page.html, I used this to navigate to registerPage

```
<ion-button size="large" routerLink="/register" routerDirection="forward" expand="block" #btnregister fill="clear" color="primary">Register</ion-button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 this.deeplink.route({
          '/registration/:userid': RegistrationPage,
          '/registration': RegistrationPage,
      }).subscribe((match) => {  
        this.router.navigateByUrl(match.$link.path, match.$args)  
        console.log("Deeplink =>", match);

        }, err => {
          console.log("Deeplink Error=>", err)
          alert("Deeplink Error=>" + err)
        })
    })
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!