# Navigation from modal page to another page in ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I am working in an ionic 4 project, and I want to navigate from modal to another page. I have tried:
`this.router.navigate(['another']);`
in my function and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting another page below the modal and closing the opened modal?

Something like this:

```
navigateToPage(){
    this.navCtrl.goForward('/page') // change page below modal
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(); // close modal
}
```

Comment: What is nav in the second line of your code? I have tried your answer and there is an error according to nav syntax and viewCtrl syntax. I have yet import the ModalController

Comment: nav: NavController and viewCtrl: ViewController you both have to import them and set them into your constructor. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I work in ionic 4 project, and it doesn't work, there is an error according to push syntax. It says "the property  push doesn't exist in the 'NavController type'"

Comment: Sorry, I missed that it is not available on ionic4. Then it should be this.navCtrl.goForward('/page');. You can also look it up here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51828017/navcontroller-doesnt-work-in-ionic-4

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your link reference, I have solved it.

Comment: The provided solution only works if I want to close the modal.
What if I want to show a detail page of an item with the intent of returning to the modal.

In my case the modal is an item selection page where the items have a "show details page"-button.

Any ideas how to cater for this use case?